# Check if device has a local authentication in Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I need to check if an apple Device has some authentication method activated in my xamarin.iOS project. For example in my xamarin Android project I can do this:

```
public bool ExistsLocalAuthenticacion() {
   KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService("keyguard");
   if (keyguardManager.IsDeviceSecure)
      return true;
   else
      return false;
}
```

I need to do something similar but in iOS project, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use [CanEvaluatePolicy()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext/1514149-canevaluatepolicy) on [deviceOwnerAuthentication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lapolicy/deviceownerauthentication):

```
var context = new LAContext();
if (context.CanEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthentication, out var error))
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
    //handle error
}
```

#### Microsoft Docs

[Use Touch ID and Face ID with Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/touch-id-face-id#local-authentication-context)